# IntelliJ IDEA/PhpStorm Creating a new file in different root folder

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA/PhpStorm. I can't find where to make this setting change, but when I create a new file through a keymap, the file is always created in the active files' directory regardless of whether I've defined a new directory or not. The file that is active is in this folder:

`app/Http/Controllers/`

I try to create a new file in a root folder named `resources/views/threads`. Here's the dialog to create a new file:

[image]

When I click 'OK', the file is placed inside a new directory structure inside the active files' directory (`app/Http/Controllers/resources/views/threads/index.blade.php`) instead of in the root folder resources directory.

[image]

I've tried preceding the new files' name with a `/` to indicate the root, but I still end up with the same issue.

Is there a setting that I need to change for the default folder for new files?

Comment: Please clarify *"new file through a keymap"* part. Do you mean when invoking "File | New" via shortcut rather than context menu/right clicking? If so -- this dialog takes current context into account (in your case -- currently opened file). I may only suggest this: move focus to a preferred location (folder) before invoking this action -- e.g. select `app` folder in Project View or Navigation panel and only then invoke this action.

Comment: It's not configurable and I personally do not know any other workarounds. I've only found this ticket -- talks about the same: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-156060 -- no feedback/comments from devs yet.

Comment: @LazyOne You're right about what I meant. I customized the keymap to that "File | New" shortcut. Thanks for responding. I'll look at that ticket.